# Loop through JQuery object

Tags: javascript, jquery, loops, each

I'm relatively new with JQuery. Let's say I have a divs structure like this:

```
<div class='quater'>
  <div id='a' class='target'></div>
  <div id='b' class='target'></div>
  <div id='c' class='no_target'></div>
</div>
```

and i would like to ad an onClick function that retrieve class "target" id's.

I tried with:

```
$('.quater').on('click', function(){
    var $value = $(this).children('.target');
    $value.each(function(){
        alert(this.attr('id'));
   });
});
```

but it returns: **undefined is not a function**

What is the right way to iterate through these elements to retrieve their ids?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try to invoke the `.attr()` function over wrapped jQuery object,

```
alert($(this).attr('id'));
```

this is a plain JavaScript object and it won't contain a member function called `.attr()`

Full code would be,

```js
  $('.quater').on('click', function() {
    var $value = $(this).children('.target');
    $value.each(function() {
      alert($(this).attr('id'));
    });
  });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class='quater'>test
  <div id='a' class='target'></div>
  <div id='b' class='target'></div>
  <div id='c' class='no_target'></div>
</div>
```

Comment: TNX a lot, obviously works like a charm, so is it the right way to iterate through JQuery selected elements? I mean is it correct to use a $variable to save the collection and iterate through it with .each() function?

Comment: @Plastic Yes it is.. And by the way glad to help.!

Comment: @Plastic Yeah caching a traversed collection of elements in a variable is usually a good practice to follow. Keep on doing that in your upcoming projects.

Comment: Thanks again, your answer will be accepted in 5 mins ^^